# How to test if my servlet called some method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit

I have a servlet:

```
class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
       String one = request.getParameter("one");
       String two = request.getParameter("two");
       addNew(one, two);
   }

   public void addNew(String one, String two){
        // DAO called here to insert a new record
   }

}
```

I want to test if 'addNew' is called without executing its body. I know that I need a Test Double, but don't know if a spy is the best way. I thought in doing this:

```
class MyServletSpy extends MyServlet
{
   private boolean addNewGotCalled = false;

   @Override
   public void addNew(String one, Integer, two)
   {
       addNewGotCalled = true;
   }

   public boolean addNewWasCalled()
   {
       return this.addNewGotCalled;
   }
}
```

Is this the right way? I feel that extending MyServlet is a litle strange, it seems that I am allowing my test to have a dependency.

Comment: Take a look at [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) maybe?

Comment: A particular method being called internally is not part of an API (usually). You should testing that for a given input the appropriate output is provided - hardcoding tests to look at class internals is often a bad sign.

Comment: why? what you're trying to achieve? use mockito `verify()` if you need to verify this in unit test

Comment: @BorisTheSpider So for test that servlet, I need to call doPost (for example) and compare the output? If my servlet access some Data (uses a DAO) I need to mock that DAO and pass it to the servlet, thats right?

Comment: @pbielicki I am trying to test the behavior of the servlet. I need to know if a method is been called for a given Request, for example. Can I use verify with objects that aren't mocks?

Comment: you can `spy` an object. not sure if this answers your question. still don't know whether you want to verify the behavior of your servlet in unit test or in production / integration test

Comment: I suggest to use Arquillian and do in-container testing, you can use mocking techniques to mock objets, but sometimes its hard and long to do  it, because you should know exactely how mocked objects should answer.

Comment: @pbielicki I just want to check if a method is called without executing its body. I know that I need a Test Double, but I can't see how to implement it in the right way. I can only think in terms of libraries as mockito or to extending my servlet to a spy or a fake.

Answer (score -1):

Quite hard to understand what you really want to test but you can try to take a look at Jetty if you want to test the behaviour of your Servlet : https://webtide.com/unit-test-servlets-with-jetty/

**EDIT**

Thanks for your clarification. In your case, one solution is to use `Mockito.spy` to test that the `addNew` method is successfully called.

First you need the mockito dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use `spy` method to test your Servlet :

```
/**
 * Test of {@link MyServlet} class
 * @author rouliboy
 */
public class MyServletTest
{
   @Test
   public void testAddNewCall() throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      // Initialization
      MyServlet myServlet = new MyServlet();
      myServlet = Mockito.spy(myServlet);

      final HttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
      final HttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

      Mockito.when(mockHttpServletRequest.getParameter("one")).thenReturn("oneReturn");
      Mockito.when(mockHttpServletRequest.getParameter("two")).thenReturn("twoReturn");

      // Test
      myServlet.doPost(mockHttpServletRequest, mockHttpServletResponse);

      // Verification
      Mockito.verify(myServlet).addNew("oneReturn", "twoReturn");
   }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

First we `spy` the Servlet using:

```
myServlet = Mockito.spy(myServlet);
```

Using `spy`, we can check which methods are called in the Servlet.

Then we mock the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` inputs of `doPost` method. Using mocks, we can define the behaviour of return values by `HttpServletRequest.getParameter(...)` :

```
Mockito.when(mockHttpServletRequest.getParameter("one")).thenReturn("oneReturn");
Mockito.when(mockHttpServletRequest.getParameter("two")).thenReturn("twoReturn");
```

And after calling `doPost` method, we verify that `addNew` is successfully called :

```
Mockito.verify(myServlet).addNew("oneReturn", "twoReturn");
```

However, I think that it would be better to test fully your Servlet (for example using Jetty and mocking your DAO) instead of just testing if your addNew method is called.

Comment: OK. In this case take a look at Mockito.

Comment: One solution is to mock HttpServletRequest and your DAO  and check that DAO is successfully called